# Need to identify compatible java version for RHEL 7

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel, redhat-openjdk

We are upgrading the RedHatLinuxEnterprise from 5.x to 7.0 and currently application is running in Java 1.7. Can we do the upgrade without upgrading java? We lso want to know the compatible version of java for RHEL 7. If there is any useful links then please share it. Thanks.

Comment: Java is cross platform, so OS upgrades shouldn't care about Java. However, Java 7 itself is end of life as of 2015

Answer (score 0):

Red Hat has extended support for OpenJDK 7 for RHEL 7 to be June 2018.  See https://access.redhat.com/articles/1299013.